# Как считать данные с консоли?

Tags: c++

Например, я пишу 'std::cout << 5'. Как мне потом это значение считать с консоли?
Upd: не самому вводить, а считать то, что уже вывело.
Какая разница, какой программой? Лишь бы значение осталось...
Комментарии с мобилы не работают

Comment: Для того чтобы вывести определенное значение надо прежде всего объявить переменную в вашем случае это может быть `int n;` потом проинициализировать с клавиатуры `std::cin>>n;` а потом при желании вывести на дисплей с помощью `std::cout<<n;` Если я все правильно понял.

Comment: Где считать? Другой программой?

Comment: Предлагаю задавать вопрос, не с "мобилы", когда будут работать комментарии

Comment: Ну, надо брать с помощью соответствующих функций API буфер консоли, указывать координаты, где именно вы хотите читать, и читать... Стоит ли эта овчинка выделки? И еще - если это другая программа, то просто пайпом `|` перенаправьте ее вывод на свой ввод и не мучьтесь :)

Answer (score 2):

судя по постановке вопроса, вашей программе требуется доступ к истории вывода ?

тогда нужно реализовывать свои потоки ввода/вывода: my::out который сохраняет копию данных в памяти (типичная реализация - кольцевой буфер), и my::in который умеет лазить в буфер за старыми данными.